# Optimize Tensorflow Object Detection Model V2 Centernet Model for Evaluation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorrt

I am using the tensorflow `centernet_resnet50_v2_512x512_kpts_coco17_tpu-8` object detection model on a Nvidia **Tesla P100** to extract **bounding boxes** and **keypoints** for detecting people in a video. Using the pre-trained from tensorflow.org, I am able to process about 16 frames per second. Is there any way I can imporve the evaluation speed for this model? Here are some ideas I have been looking into:

- **Pruning the model graph** since I am only detecting 1 type of object (people)

  - Have not been successful in doing this. Changing the `label_map` when building the model does not seem to improve performance.
- **Hard coding the input size**

  - Have not found a good way to do this.
- **Compiling the model** to an optimized form using something like **TensorRT**

  - Initial attempts to convert to TensorRT did not have any performance improvements.
- **Batching** predictions

  - It looks like the pre-trained model has the batch size hard coded to 1, and so far when I try to change this using the `model_builder` I see a drop in performance.
  - My GPU utilization is about ~75% so I don't know if there is much to gain here.

Answer (score 3):

TensorRT should in most cases give a large increase in frames per second compared to Tensorflow.

`centernet_resnet50_v2_512x512_kpts_coco17_tpu-8` can be found in the TensorFlow Model Zoo.
Nvidia has released a blog post describing how to optimize models from the TensorFlow Model Zoo using Deepstream and TensorRT:
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/deploying-models-from-tensorflow-model-zoo-using-deepstream-and-triton-inference-server/

Now regarding your suggestions:

- **Pruning the model graph**: Pruning the model graph can be done by converting your tensorflow model to a TF-TRT model.
- **Hardcoding the input size**: Use the static mode in TF-TRT. This is the default mode and enabled by: `is_dynamic_op=False`
- **Compiling the model**: My advise would be to convert you model to TF-TRT or first to ONNX and then to TensorRT.
- **Batching**: Specifying the batch size is also covered in the NVIDIA blog post.

Lastly, for my model a big increase in performance came from using FP16 in my inference engine. ([mixed precision](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#mixed_precision)) You could even try INT8 although then you first have to callibrate.